# jQuery does not hit the Ajax URL on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to implement a poll plugin on wordpress. The jQuery onchange event is working very fine of the below script but doesn't call or display the ajax hit on network .

**plugin index page
PHP :**

```
 function my_scripts_main() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'my_voter_script',
            plugins_url( '/js/main.js' , __FILE__ ),
            array( 'jquery' )
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 
            'myAjax',
             array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'action'=>'my_poll_srt')
        );        
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_main' );
```

**Plugin Short code Page :**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_poll_srt', 'my_poll_srt_callbck' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_poll_srt', 'my_poll_srt_callbck' );


function my_poll_srt_callbck() {
    global $wpdb;
    $poll_id=$_POST['poll_id'];
    $answer=$_POST['answer'];
    $d=mktime(11, 14, 54, 8, 12, 2014);
    $created= date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);

    /******* My Logic ****************/


    echo json_encode(array('YES'=>$count_yes,
            'NO'=>$count_no));
     wp_die();
}
```

**JS script :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery("input[name=answer_srt]:radio").change(function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                             //   submit();
                               //  $(this).closest("form").submit(function() {
                                   // alert('Hello');
                                    var poll_answer=$(this).val();
                                    var poll_id=jQuery(this).closest("form").find('#poll_id_srt').val();
                                    var vi=jQuery(this);



                                 jQuery.ajax({
                                    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        action: myAjax.action,
                                        answer:poll_answer,
                                        poll_id:poll_id
                                    },
                                   // dataType: 'html',
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                                     //   console.log(obj);
                                        jQuery(vi).closest('form').find('#poll_sht').html('YES='+obj.YES+'   NO='+obj.NO);

                                    }
                              //  });

                                 });
                            }); 
                         });
```

In the code above there are no errors in console panel.

If I put `alert()` inside the script its working fine but its not hitting admin-ajax.php file. What to do now ? Where am I wrong please help me ?[image: As you can see no ajax call but alert is working fine on change event]

Comment: Why is your data parameter commented out? You need that as it sets the correct action.

Comment: sorry .. its for testing perpose .. but same happend without comment also

Comment: Try changing your `add_actions` to: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_poll_srt_callbck', 'my_poll_srt_callbck' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_poll_srt_callbck', 'my_poll_srt_callbck' );`

Comment: In JS script Remove
` jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

});` And Try.

Comment: @dingo_d I have already using `add_action`

Comment: @DevDanidhariya i dont think its problm cuz alert function is working fine with displaying poll value

Comment: include wp-load.php file in your php AJAX File.

Comment: Change "type: 'post'" to "method: 'post'" in your ajax call.

Comment: I know you have, but I was just wondering if you tried using the same syntax for actions, add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ **my_poll_srt_callbck**', '**my_poll_srt_callbck**' ); add_action( 'wp_ajax_ **my_poll_srt_callbck**', '**my_poll_srt_callbck**' ); Notice that the bold parts are the same, whereas on your actions they aren't.

Comment: I just pasted your code into an empty theme, and it works fine. The only change (other than putting it in a theme, not a plugin) I made was to change `var poll_answer=$(this).val();` to `var poll_answer=jQuery(this).val();`. You say there are no errors in your console, so perhaps `$` is defined as something other than `jQuery`.  Other than that, if you have several forms per page, your HTML may be invalid (eg you'll have several elements with ID `poll_id_srt` - change that to a class). But I don't think that's causing an issue. If the `$`/`jQuery` switch doesn't help, can you paste your HTML?

Comment: thanks guys . Suddenly its working fine , i don't know how i have fixed it . but its working fine Thanks guys for your support . ( I have not change my  any code . Then How  ??  )

Comment: if you are using a caching system with "cache php files" enabled - it could simply be that your cache expired.

Comment: Was wondering why sometimes you were using $ instead of jQuery as in `var poll_answer=$(this).val();` and also thought storing `jQuery(this)` in a variable would be a best practice if you will use it in the code 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Your action URL should contain query string of action.
e.g
The action URL is like this
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_poll_srt